# Reclassifying elements of a dataset according to some key

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I have a large array of names belonging to a given range name_range_old.
example:

```
name_range_old = [name1, name2]

names = [name1, name2, name1, name1, ...]
```

I want to reclassify each element according to different criterion (names in debt_range). I have done it in a way that might not be optimal, and I am looking for alternatives that might be faster.

Here is my attempt:

```
names_list = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'E', 'F', 'B', 'G', 'G', 'D', 'H']
name_range_old = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
name_range_new = ['K', 'U', 'V']
n_names = len(name_range_new)

name_index = []                    # This index maps the old range to the new
name_index.append([0, 1, 2, 10])                        
name_index.append([3, 4, 5, 6])
name_index.append([7, 8, 9])               

def classifier(name):
    a = [i for i in range(n_names) if name in 
name_range_old[name_index[i]]]
    return name_range_new[a[0]]

names_list = [classifier(name) for name in names_list]
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question with some code that runs? Your code doesn't work currently because the last line references `names_list` before it has been defined.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that reference was missing. Updated and hopefully now it's clearer

Comment: Your code *still* does not run. I see `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list` for line `a = [i for i in range(n_names) if name == name_range_old[name_index[i]]]`